# Java Jnlp CodeSigner Error

Tags: java, jnlp

I am trying to run a java jnlp application from my computer. Every time I try launch the file I get the error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/security/CodeSigner`

From searching Google it seems to be a common enough problem and is normally blamed on 'java 6'. I couldn't find a solution that doesn't involve rolling back to an older java version.

Does anyone know how fix this without reverting versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like SUN JRE 1.6.0_14 [was the last SUN JVM without that nasty bug](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5402886)... I'd install that version in parallel and use it more or less exclusively for jnlp applications, that still request Java 1.4. (guess you can't change the jnlp application so that it request a higher Java version)